# nginx - redirect all requests for files which do not exist to index page?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a simple website with 1 html file `index.html`. I want that all user that type `example.com/abcde` will be redirected to `example.com`
Of course, all links to resource files (images/css/js etc.) should work

Currently, I have this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

This setup works, users see index page if they try to open `example.com/abcde`. But URL in the browser does not change... How to rewrite the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a rewrite.

You could use a redirect as a fallback location :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    return 301 http://example.com;
}
```

Comment: Beware that using a 301 redirect may pose obstacles if you want to use the URI later on. permanent redirects are cached by browsers.

Comment: @r_3 You are totally right, and i'm aware of this. A 302 redirect (temporary redirect) could be used...